# Showing that there exists three points, joined by lines of the same colour

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Every one of six points is joined to every other one by either a red or a blue line. Show that there exists three of the points joined by lines of the same colour.

I'm not sure how to do this. We haven't learnt any combinatorial methods yet, and this is just inside the problem set under the Proofs topic.
All I know is that there will be $5+4+3+2+1=15$ lines in total.

Comment: Fix one point. There are (at least) three other points joined to it by lines of the same color, say blue.  Consider the cases: 1) no two of these three points are joined to each other by a blue line. 2) otherwise...

Comment: Thanks everyone. Curious - is there a way to do this by contradiction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose one point, and call it $p$. Then, from $p$ to other points, there  are five lines, each being possibly one of two colors. Clearly, at least three of them must be of the same color, say red. Let these go to the points $a,b,c$.

Case 1: If any one of $ab,bc$ or $ca$ is coloured red, then the triangle $abp,bcp,cap$ will have all red coloured sides respectively.

Case 2: If none of these sides is coloured red, these are coloured blue, hence the triangle $abc$ is blue.

Hence, either way we have a blue or red coloured triangle.

The interesting thing is, that with five vertices this is not necessarily true.

Moreover, it is worth asking what would be the minimum number of vertices for which a triangle will be a certainty if there were three colours involved, say red,blue,green.

This is all part of the study field of [Ramsey Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey_theory).

Comment: Thank you. For that aside, is there a known "formula" or method to calculate the number of vertices needed for $N$ colours such that they there exists $N+1$ points connected just with one colour? (I chose $N+1$ because in the question we had $2$ colours, and wanted $3$ points).

Comment: No, I  don't know of any such formula, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Fix one point $A$. There are five other points connected to $A$, so there has to be at least three points (call them $B,C,D$) connected to $A$ with the same color, say blue (you might want to draw a picture of this situation). Now there are two possibilities:

1) One of the lines between two of the points $B,C,D$ is blue. Then you pick these two points together with point $A$ and you have your triangle.

2) All lines between the points $B,C,D$ are red. Then...

I think you can fill out the rest and the details. It really helps to draw a picture of the situation.

Comment: It's always hard to pick between two answers that both equally helped me. I chose the other one because it had background information on it as well (Ramsey Theory) that I didn't know of. Thank you